# Matrices in $F_n^m$ proof

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let F be a field and X, Y two F-linear subspaces with $dim_FX=n\in \mathbb{N}$ and $dim_FY=m\in \mathbb{N}$.

To show:

a)There exists a matrix $A\in F_n^m$ with $def(A)=0 \iff n\leq m$

b)There exists a matrix $A\in F_n^m$ with $rnk(A)=m \iff n\geq m$

does A has to be m x n or n x m?
And can it be smaller in order to still be $\in F_n^m$ like (m-1)x(n-1)

Is $F_n^m$ the space for the $Dim(V)=n−rank(A)$-Formular? And which dimension has $F_n^m$ then? (n i guess?)

$def(A)=dim_FKernel(A)$

Comment: Sorry, what is def of a matrix?

Comment: hi, its the dimension of the kernel of the matrix, edited it into my question